# bndtools pom repository local path

Tags: bndtools

Does the `local` parameter of
`aQute.bnd.repository.maven.pom.provider.BndPomRepository;`
support relative paths? And if yes, based from where: the osgi-workspace, or the osgi-project?

Comment: Why do you not create a absolute path from the relative one with a macro usage
e.g. `local=${osfile;{.}/.m2/repository;}`

Comment: Because the location of the repo in my context can be in many different places. And is typically relative to the build path.

Comment: Which is the case in above macro. Just during build it is evaluated at that moment into an absolute path.

Comment: Greatl. So this is indeed the answer. I didn't know that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro like `local=${osfile;{.}/.m2/repository;}`
This will create a absolute path on execution/access of bnd to the value.
The macro is resolving an absolute path from the relative path.